# Is it enough to beware of big sins?

Tags: quran, tafseer

> If you avoid the major sins which you are forbidden, We will remove
> from you your lesser sins and admit you to a noble entrance [into
> Paradise]. (31)

Is it enough to beware of big sins to get to Heaven? Is it necessary to do righteous deeds, as it is said in many verses, if it is said in 4:31 that it is enough to beware of great sins?

Answer (score 1):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you and your family are doing well. If you avoid the major sins then Alhamdullilah you should be good for the rest of your life. The following hadith states:

> Verily the Messenger of ALLAAH (ﷺ) said: The five (daily) prayers and from one Friday prayer to the (next) Friday prayer, and from Ramadhan to Ramadhan are expiations for the (sins) committed in between (their intervals) provided one shuns the major sins. (Muslim, Chapter of Purification)

Furthermore, the main ticket to get into heaven is the kalimah. The belief in One God without any partners and to believe in what was sent down (Quraan). And everything else that comes with the revelation. If you do not believe in it 100% then you are an unbeliever. Sins do not make one a unbeliever however, it inches towards disbelief and lowers your spirituality until you come to gates of leaving Islam. May ALLAAH (Glory Be To Him) protect us all. Ameen.

**Have a Nice Day!**

**Note #1:** If you downvote my answer, please be courteous and say why you downvoted in a comment below.

**Note #2:** This is my own personal answer that I have derived from what I have researched.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a general principle, minor sins if done repeatedly become major sins. So no it not necessarily enough, but in cases people are forgiven despite all their minor sins, doing good deeds erases these things as well as repentance

Comment: Does a Muslim become a non-true believer at the time of committing a great sin (for example, murder) or before his repentance? By a true believer, I mean those to whom Allah has promised Paradise (Quran 8:4, 9:72, 58:22, 33:47). According to the Quran, can a true believer commit a grave sin?